# Rails : Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, ruby-on-rails-5

I get this error on my `posts` index page :

[image]

This the model :

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  include Filterable

  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :topic
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :published_at, presence: true
  translates :title, :content, :slug, touch: true, fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { thumb: "100x70#", featured: "1560x868#", small: "760x868#", big: ">1600x1600" }
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
  validates_attachment_presence :image

  scope :published, -> (published) { where(published: (['true', true].include? published)).order(featured: :desc, published_at: :desc) }
  scope :published_until_now, -> { where("published_at < ?", Time.now).merge(Post.published(true)) }
  scope :topic, -> (topic_id) {
    joins(:topic).where('topic_id = ?', topic_id) }
  scope :category, -> (post_category) {
    joins(:category).where('category_id = ?', post_category) }
  scope :match, -> (search_term) {
    with_translations(I18n.locale).where('content like ? or title like ?', "%#{search_term}%", "%#{search_term}%") }

  self.per_page = 10

  after_save :unfeature_older_posts, if: Proc.new { |post| post.featured? }

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :globalize

  def unfeature_older_posts
    featured_posts = Post.where(featured: true).where.not(id: id).order(published_at: :desc)
    if featured_posts.size == 1
      featured_posts.last.update(featured: false)
    end
  end

end
```

This the controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :get_pages_tree, :get_privacy_policy, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @filters = params.slice(:topic, :category)
    @posts = Post.published_until_now
      .filter(@filters)
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 11)
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and `filter` is defined here :

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I recently upgraded to Ruby on Rails 5 and Ruby 2.7.0, I don't know if it's related.

Comment: Can you show us your Post model file?

Comment: @gabrimac I updated the question by adding the model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try replacing `module ClassMethods` with `class_methods do`.

If it works, then please keep in mind:

---

`filter` method comes from Ruby. It's defined in `Array`. As you can see in the [doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-filter), `filter` method on `Array` takes no argument. That's the direct cause of the error you see.

In Rails, when methods on `Array` are called on `ActiveRecord` object (in your case, `Post.published_until_now`) and when methods cannot be found on a model, it automatically converts itself into an `Array`. So, it calls `filter` method on `Array`. Generally, you don't want to define methods such as `filter` which is confusing.

Comment: Replacing `module ClassMethods` also gave me an error, but you put me on the right track, I renamed the `filter` method to `filter_posts` and it works now.